# Захват звука с мишкера

Tags: java, аудио, запись

Доброго времени суток , Нужна помощь как захватить звук с мишкера системы?

```
    AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(48000, 16, 2, true, false);
    Mixer.Info[] mixersInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    Mixer.Info selectedMixerInfo = mixersInfo[0];
    TargetDataLine recordLine = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(audioFormat, selectedMixerInfo);

    recordLine.open(audioFormat);
    recordLine.start();


    // К примеру
    System.out.println(recordLine.getLevel());
```

Получаю
(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface TargetDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian) менял форматы всё аналогично(

Comment: гуглить пробовали?

Comment: Да гуглил ,но те примеры были нерабочие

Comment: приводите примеры, которые вы пробовали и указывайте, что не работало. Люди помогут исправить ошибки, но писать за вас тут никто не будет.

Answer (score 1):

> Получаю
>   (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface TargetDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian) менял форматы всё аналогично(

Микшер не поддерживает соотв. формат, для проверки можно использовать:

```
boolean supported = AudioSystem.getMixer(selectedMixerInfo).isLineSupported(recordLine.getLineInfo());
```

Вот тут предлагают варианты получения поддерживаемых форматов - [Java - recording from mixer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002444/java-recording-from-mixer).
Вот рабочий пример захвата звука с микрофона и последующего вывода [Java example for capturing and playing data from microphone](https://gist.github.com/fedor-rusak/2294168):

```
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 2, true, false);
DataLine.Info targetInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
DataLine.Info sourceInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);

try {
    TargetDataLine targetLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(targetInfo);
    targetLine.open(format);
    targetLine.start();

    SourceDataLine sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(sourceInfo);
    sourceLine.open(format);
    sourceLine.start();

    int numBytesRead;
    byte[] targetData = new byte[targetLine.getBufferSize() / 5];

    while (true) {
        numBytesRead = targetLine.read(targetData, 0, targetData.length);
        if (numBytesRead == -1) break;
        sourceLine.write(targetData, 0, numBytesRead);
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, что то я туплю а как мне считать с мишкера?